# Configure proxy_pass for intermittent service

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm using Nginx within a Doccker container to host my application

I'm trying to configure Nginx to proxy traffic to the /.well-known/ directory to another container that handles the letsencrypt process to setup & renew SSL certificates, but I don't need that container to be running all the time, only when attempting to renew the certificates.

My idea was to use proxy_pass for the directory specific traffic, through to the leysencrypt container, but as it's not always running, the Nginx process exits complaining that the upstream is not available.

Is there a way to configure Nginx not to check the status of the upstream for proxy_pass setting?

Here's the current config, if it's useful…

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name domain.com;

    root /var/www/html/web;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/ {
        proxy_pass http://letsencrypt/.well-known/;
    }
}
```

I guess I could use an in app forwarding of files, but this feels clunky.  I'd rather configure it within Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /.well-known/ {
  resolver 127.0.0.1;
  set $upstream letsencrypt;
  proxy_pass http://$upstream/.well-known/; # use variables to make nginx startable
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little details of what this is doing, please?  How does it prevent nginx checking that the upstream server is available?

Comment: Just make nginx startable, will still generate error code (503...).